# Facebook API Access Token Server Side

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-authentication

I am pretty new to the Facebook API and am using the Javascript SDK to do most of my work. I am logging in with:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        document.location.href = '<%: ResolveUrl("~/Account") %>/AuthenticateFacebook?accessToken=' + encodeURI(response.authResponse.accessToken) + '&userID=' + encodeURI(response.authResponse.userID) + '&returnUrl=' + $('#returnUrl').val();
    }
}
```

This is sending the result of the login response to my authenticate page. This is working fine. Later on when I want to use the `accessToken` on the server is where I am stuck.

I am also trying to use the [Facebook C# SDK](http://csharpsdk.org/) to do basic stuff. That requires the `accessToken` so my question is how can I access the from servers side, or do I store that somewhere?

The site is MVC3 with a basic ASP.NET membership service underneath. Any help or guidance on this is really appreciated.

Comment: avoid redirecting to a url with access_token as that would store the access token in the browser history.

Comment: @prabir, How do you suggest passing that? POST it via AJAX or something? Should we run that traffic over HTTPS? Also nice work on the SDK!!!

Comment: use ajax via https or user server side oauth flow

Comment: Do you have an example of the server side oauth flow. I could not find it in the sdk docs. I am using 5.4, latest nuget release.

Comment: as of now there are no samples, you can easily implement by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have so far is excellent.  It is the way that the C# SDK developers want you to do it.

To store it server-side, you can place that into session.  Bear in mind that the access token is only good for an hour or so.  So occasionally you will want to grab a new token client-side to refresh the one on your server.

You have a few options more than just dropping it into session:

- Session variable (as mentioned)
- App cache
- memcached
- database

Comment: OK, so basically we want to treat the `accessToken` as temporary. Is there a way server side to retrieve a new one? Otherwise I would end up doing a lot of back and forth to get the new one on the server side.

Comment: To add to my comment I see in the docs, http://csharpsdk.org/docs/web/handling-expired-access-tokens.html,  the section "Renewing an access token", however it is not complete. That is exactly what I would like to do.

Comment: So disregard the last comments. It was an issue of using the right tool for the job. Basically I have a friends list that I was pulling in the C$ SDK, which required the accessToken. Pulling that list via `JSON` with an jQuery AJAX call and passing the current accessToken was the way to go. Very easy in the end. Thank you for helping me realize the correct methodology.

Comment: Bo worries. Glad to help.  (It's good to wake up to a solved problem  :) )